# Scala Predicates

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and I'm trying to figure out what predicates are and the correct way to used them. The information I found online is not very clear to me or it assumes previous knowledge of predicates. Can someone explain what they are and perhaps show a few examples of how to use them in Scala?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A predicate is a function that returns a `Boolean`.

For example, to check if an Integer is even we can define the function `isEven`.

```
scala> def isEven(i: Int) = i % 2 == 0
isEven: (i: Int)Boolean
```

It behaves as you would expect.

```
scala> isEven(2)
res1: Boolean = true
```

So, you can then pass this into a function like `filter` that takes a function that returns a boolean. The type signature for this is `p: (A) ⇒ Boolean)` where `p` is short for predicate.

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).filter(isEven)
res2: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
```

See [Scala School](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/) for some good reading.